# Read Excel sheet from PowerShell - Display issue

Tags: excel, powershell

Thanks you Theo. Now its look better but I prefer to display each one in the same row and not as below:

[image]

I have a script that can read from an excel all the columns. The user need to choose the right column so I am displaying the table but it look very bad (Also tried with | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap that display it 2 rows. without the -AutoSize there is only the start with ...)

In addition how can I search according to background color and string?
I am using this for color:

```
  $val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnNumber).Interior.ColorIndex
    if ($val -eq $searchcolorForPatch)  {
        # output an object with both values from columns A and B
        [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2}
```

And this for string:

```
$val2 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnNumber).value2
if ($val2 -match $searchValue)  {
    # output an object with both values from columns A and B
    [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2}
```

I want to get a result only if I have a specific color and a string inside

```
# get the number of rows in the sheet
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# get the number of columns in the sheet
$colMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# create a hash with column header names and their indices
$columns = [ordered]@{}
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $name = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value()  # assuming the first row has the headers
    if ($name -ne $null){
    $columns[$name] = $col} 
}
$columns   | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Each result should be in one row

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the third code, you get a (ordered) Hashtable of the Excel column Names combined with their indices:

```
# get the number of rows in the sheet
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# get the number of columns in the sheet
$colMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# create a hash with column header names and their indices
$columns = [ordered]@{}
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $name = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value()  # assuming the first row has the headers
    if ($name -match '\S'){
    $columns[$name] = $col} 
}
```

If you now want to present this HashTable of column names / Excel column indices as a menu to the user, you could do this:

```
# draw the menu
$columns.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    # {0,2} means to write the index number from $_.Value right aligned for two digits
    '{0,2}: {1}' -f $_.Value, $_.Name
}
Write-Host  # add an empty line

# quick and dirty..
do {
    $answer = Read-Host "Please enter the number of the update you need to install. Press Q to exit"
    # ask this question until the user enters a number or 'Q'
} until ($answer -eq 'Q' -or $answer -match '^\d{1,2}$')
```

Next examine what the user typed in and perform the appropriate action

Either using a switch like this:

```
switch ($answer) {
    'Q'  { break } # user wants to quit
    '1'  { <# run 'Patch 7.5.31.29' #> }
    '2'  { <# run 'Bulk Tool 7.5.40.197-7.5.40.300' #> }
    '3'  { <# run 'Side VIP 8.6.22' #> }
    # and so on
}
```

Or more generic like:

```
switch ($answer) {
    'Q'  { break } # user wants to quit
    {1..$columns.Count} {
        # get the Name from the chosen value
        $action = $columns.Keys | Where-Object {$columns["$_"] -eq $answer}
        Write-Host "You chose to perform '$action'" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        <# run $action #>
    }
}
```

This is what it will look like on screen:

```
 1: Patch 7.5.31.29
 2: Bulk Tool 7.5.40.197-7.5.40.300
 3: Side VIP 8.6.22

Please enter the number of the update you need to install. Press Q to exit: 2
You chose to perform 'Bulk Tool 7.5.40.197-7.5.40.300'
```

Comment: Thank you about that, The excel is dynamic.. I need to read it every time. So hard coded is not so good for me

Comment: @NirCarmona Sure, that was only to serve as example for other readers. You keep the code to read from Excel

Comment: Not sure I understand you. I need to insert the updated column every update?
$columns = [ordered]@{
    'Patch 7.5.31.29'                 = 1
    'Bulk Tool 7.5.40.197-7.5.40.300' = 2
    'Side VIP 8.6.22'                 = 3
    # and so on
}

Comment: @NirCarmona No, as said, I only put that in as example for others. You do not use the hardcoded Hash, since you have the code to read that from your Excel files. Then, instead of doing `$columns | Format-Table`, you add the code starting with `# draw the menu`

Comment: @NirCarmona Ok, I changed my answer to include the code where you build the `$columns` Hashtable from Excel and removed the hardcoded example for clarity

Comment: From the # draw the menu untill the end?
Sorry for my question :)

Comment: @NirCarmona From where it says `Either using a switch like this:` you add the last code block, the one underneath `Or more generic like:`. The code block above that is only of use if you know how many options you will have. Since you create it all dynamic from an Excel file, the generic method is best for you.

Comment: Thank you Theo, I took 2 blocks, this that starts with # draw the menu  and this: 
Or more generic like:
I see the menu now. Some rows display as 2 rows. There is an option to display in 1 row even if the name is long?

Comment: Regarding to my second question (search according to background color and string)
Maybe you have a solution for me?